# mistake with finish an activity in android

Tags: back, activity-finish

I have a main activity with 6 buttons. Every button starts a new activity.
The program worked well but after that I changed some graphical attributes and made some changes in the theme a mistake occurred . I should press back button 3 times to return from an activity or exit from the main activity. Any suggestions?

```
btn_weeks.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Weeks.class);
    startActivity(i);
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons should implements `View.OnClickListener` and not `OnTouchListener`.